# WCF “At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements”

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to consume my WCF webservice via an MVC Web Application. I add a service reference via the Add service reference dialogue in VS. Now when I try to call my proxy.LoginUser I get the error message:

Operation 'GetAlertNotification' of contract 'IService1' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

The only problem is there is no body parameters in GetAlertNotification?? If I understand correctly if I pass all parameters via the query string this should not be an issue? Here is the signature of GetAlertNotification in IService:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetAlertNotification?project={project}&currentversion={currentversion}&EncryptData={EncryptData}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    AlertNotification GetAlertNotification(string project, string currentversion, bool EncryptData = false);
```

Edit:
I replaced WebInvoke by WebGet and still get the error message above. How can it say it has multiple request body parameters with everything specified in the UriTemplate? I'm I not understanding what the error is saying? Anynone?

Comment: Could it be the error is referring to the response object which should be wrapped?

Also, maybe this post can help you.

http://www.wcf.dotnetarchives.com/2013/12/difference-between-webmessagebodystylew.html

Comment: Well the error explicitly says: specifies multiple **request** body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `BodyStyle` property to `Wrapped` as the error message suggested?

Comment: @Tim I want to confirm cause I may not understand properly. Does 'GetAlertNotification' like I posted above specify multiple request body parameters to be serialized? If not why would I need to set the BodyStyle to Wrapped?